# How to set custom filter in form validation in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter's [form validation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html). Here is an example:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
```

The documentation say:

> Any native PHP function that accepts one parameter can be used as a
>   rule, like htmlspecialchars, trim, MD5, etc.

What if I want the value to pass through my own *custom* filter? For example, I would like the value to be cleaned of "badWord".

```
function curseWordRemove($original = '') {
    return str_replace('badWord', '', $original);
}
```

CodeIgniter already provides ways to do custom validation, but not custom filters. The custom validation only returns true or false, not the filtered string.

```
function isPolite($string = '') {
    if (strpos($string, 'badWord') !== false) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message(
            'fieldName',
            'contains a very bad word'
        );
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Codeigniter has a helper that lets filters out "bad words" http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/text_helper.html

Comment: @RPM how do I integrate this with form validation? Also, keep in mind, I need more custom filters than just curse-word removal.

Comment: Do you the words you need to filter? Or does the system need to be able to decide if it should censor the word?

Comment: @RPM The curse-word removal is just an example. In my real application, I have no need to remove curse words. Rather, I have some other complex filters - ones that remove spam by analyzing the language. My root problem is not how to do curse-word removal. I need to attach a number of custom filters to CodeIgniter's form validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jojo, you must have missed it the userguide, its called a `callback`, and here is [the documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks).

An Example:

```
<?php

class Form extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'callback_username_check');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|is_unique[users.email]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('myform');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('formsuccess');
        }
    }

    public function username_check($str)
    {
        if ($str == 'test')
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'The %s field can not be the word "test"');
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Basically, create a validation called `callback_check_bad_words` and a matching function in your controller called `check_bad_words($value)`.  Return a boolean as a result (as the result goes back to the validation).

Since you can only pass back a boolean, you need to either use a global variable, OR run the 'sanitization' of your word later on, you don't need it in validation UNLESS you want to stop it from submission.

If your intent is to sanitize the input for bad words, just do it, don't validate for it.

Comment: @JoJo, well you would just AFTER validating do whatever you liked, make sure to get the value from `$this->input->post('value');`